# Iterate a list using recursion

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, recursion

How can I write this same function using recursion?

```
def replace(thelist,a,b):
"""Returns: a COPY of thelist but with all occurrences of a replaced by b. 

    Example: replace([1,2,3,1], 1, 4) = [4,2,3,4].

Precondition: thelist is a list of ints
              a and b are ints"""
```

I believe I'm supposed to make a copy of the original, and then from there make a = b in the list, but I do not know how to implement that. Please help me solve this, and thank you!

Comment: Why does it have to utilize recursion?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Show some code.

Comment: this problem is for practice with recursion

Comment: newlist = thelist[:]
    
    if newlist == []:
        return 0
    
    
    return ( a = b if newlist[0] == a else a) + replace(newlist[1:],a,b)

Comment: I know some of it is wrong but I'm not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def replace(thelist, a, b):
    if not thelist:
        return []
    elif thelist[0] == a:
        return [b] + replace(thelist[1:], a, b)
    else:
        return [thelist[0]] + replace(thelist[1:], a, b)
```

It's a recursive solution, and works as expected:

```
replace([1, 2, 3, 1], 1, 4)
=> [4, 2, 3, 4]
```